# JPAQuery.fetchResults() is deprecated, how should I replace it?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I use querydsl-core 5.0.0; when I get the paged data, I found that JPAQuery.fetchResults() has been deprecated. Now what method do I need to use to achieve the paged data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Quo.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The morale behind is is that there is that `fetchResults` never properly worked in the first place (in some cases) and there is no way to implement it properly with just the syntax JPQL (the query language of JPA) allows.

If `fetchResults` worked for you before, you can keep using it. But only do so when you actually need the total count. Because `fetchResults` is a misleading name, often users will only need `fetch()`, which is obviously preferred as it does not suffer from the flaws `fetchResults` has.

While `fetchResults` will remain available for a fair amount of time (although its use is discouraged under JPA), you are likely to end up in situations where `fetchResults` does not work. If you do need proper pagination, that also work on queries with aggregations, I recommend using the [Querydsl integration for Blaze-Persistence](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration), which has advanced pagination functionality:

```java
public PagedList<Employee> Employees(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    return new BlazeJPAQuery(entityManager, criteriaBuilderFactory).from(employee)
        .orderBy(employee.id.asc())
        .select(employee)
        .fetchPage(firstResult, maxResults);
}
```

Using this advanced pagination, it also implements `fetchResults()` properly, so your old code keeps working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the API documentation it suggests to use `fetch()` method.

**Documentation:**

[Mind that for any scenario where the count is not strictly needed separately, we recommend to use {@link #fetch()} instead.](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-jpa/src/main/java/com/querydsl/jpa/impl/AbstractJPAQuery.java)